# spawning arrays of obstacles 2d runner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make 2d runner and I have the following problem: I want to spawn another array of gameobjects when the value `xValueForArray` - which represents end of the previously spawned array - becomes smaller than the value of `spawnerVal` on the x axis.

What happens with this code is that `xValueForArray` always keeps the value from first `update()` and camera moves on `x` axis. So, in `update` the value `xValueForArray` is always smaller than `spawnerVal`. In consequence, the array spawner just creates hundreds of arrays per second because the conditional in `update` is always true.

How can I make `xValueForArray` value of last spawned array?

```
void Start ()
{
    creatingArray(); //creating first array
}

void Update ()
{
    xValueForArray = tempArray.GetComponent<arrayOfBoxes>().Xvalue; // position on x of the last element in array
    spawnerVal = spawner.transform.position.x - valX; // position from which I spawn arrays of elements
    if (xValueForArray < spawnerVal) // if value of xValueForArray is less than value of spawnerVal call creatingArray();
        creatingArray();
}

void creatingArray()
{
    int poz = Random.Range(0, obstacle.Length);
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(obstacle[poz], spawner.transform.position, spawner.transform.rotation);
    tempArray = temp;
}
```

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to name variabeles this way. Try to use english names for better readability)

Comment: And that is especially useful when you show your code to other developers that don't speak your native language... like on Stack Overflow for instance ;)

Comment: yep, thanks for suggestion, i edited it